# change column alias and its display format using stored procedure in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_SalHireDate_18127057
(
 salAlias VARCHAR,
 hireDateAlias VARCHAR,
 salDisplayFormat VARCHAR,
 hireDateFormat VARCHAR
)
AS
  sysRefCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN sysRefCursor FOR 
  SELECT SAL TO_CHAR(salAlias), HIREDATE TO_CHAR(hireDateAlias)
  FROM EMP_18127057;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(sysRefCursor);
END;
```

What i want to do is, when passing the alias and its display format(Ex: salary: 1000 to 1000.00; date: dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy), the procedure will display the two columns with alias as their names and show their values in new format. I still don't figure out the code.Can anyone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't know a procedure could return something.  I think your select statement should respect Oracle syntax.

Comment: Don't do this; it is just asking for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You can use dbms_sql to return implicit results. This was a feature added to Oracle 12 to ease the migration from SQL Server.

Comment: My question is a home exercise. Please help me to solve the main problems.

Comment: By the way, your VARCHARs should be the standard type, VARCHAR2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dynamic SQL to include the aliases in the output:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_SalHireDate_18127057
(
  salAlias         VARCHAR2,
  hireDateAlias    VARCHAR2,
  salDisplayFormat VARCHAR2,
  hireDateFormat   VARCHAR2
)
AS
  sysRefCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN sysRefCursor
  FOR 'SELECT TO_CHAR( sal, :s ) AS ' || salAlias
      || ', TO_CHAR( hiredate, :h ) AS ' || hireDateAlias
      || ' FROM EMP_18127057' USING salDisplayFormat, hireDateFormat;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(sysRefCursor);
END;
/
```

However, don't do this as you will introduce SQL injection attacks and can make queries such as:

```sql
sp_SalHireDate_18127057(
  'salary',
  'hd, ( SELECT password_hash FROM secret_table WHERE username = ''ADMIN'' ) AS pwd',
  '99999999.00',
  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'
);
```

Which will return an extra column and data from a table you were not expecting the user to have access to.

---

## Update

If you want to also assert that the aliases are simple SQL identifiers then you can wrap then in a call to `DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_SalHireDate_18127057
(
  salAlias         VARCHAR2,
  hireDateAlias    VARCHAR2,
  salDisplayFormat VARCHAR2,
  hireDateFormat   VARCHAR2
)
AS
  sysRefCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN sysRefCursor
  FOR 'SELECT TO_CHAR( sal, :s ) AS ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME( salAlias )
      || ', TO_CHAR( hiredate, :h ) AS ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME( hireDateAlias )
      || ' FROM EMP_18127057' USING salDisplayFormat, hireDateFormat;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(sysRefCursor);
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  sp_SalHireDate_18127057( 'salary', 'hd, ( SELECT password_hash FROM secret_table WHERE username = ''ADMIN'' ) AS pwd', '99999999.00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' );
END;
/
```

Would output:

> ```
> ORA-44003: invalid SQL name
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 215
> ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA_NAME.SP_SALHIREDATE_18127057", line 11
> ORA-06512: at line 2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7461d9278a15b4b4ba2ba5b4b9c77dc6)*

Answer (score -2):

Use this select:

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(salAlias, salDisplayFormat) SAL, TO_CHAR(hireDateAlias, hireDateFormat) HIREDATE
```

Comment: "the procedure will display the two columns with alias as their names" This displays the alias and not the aliased column value.